# Adding an .exe file to registry on Windows run at startup - via Python

Tags: python, windows, registry, python-3.4

I have a script and I'll make it .exe, I want to put it to registry so it'll run at startup, when computer is on. I put this line at the start of the script

```
exec(r"""REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "myfile" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\Users\windows\Desktop\myfile\myExe.exe""")
```

It raises `SyntaxError` every time. I don't even understand why it does this. I changed `"""` to `""` but not worked. I tried lots of things, everytime syntax error. How can I add an .exe to registry so it can run when computer is on?

And no, I don't want to put it to start-up folder manually, I have to do this via registry.

Comment: `exec` executes Python source code. To run reg.exe you can use the following: `import subprocess;` `subprocess.call(r'reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "myfile" /t REG_SZ /f /d "%s"' % myExe_path)`.

Comment: @eryksun I'm going to try this.

Comment: Or use the winreg module: `import winreg;` `key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE);` `winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'myFile', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, myExe_path);`
`key.Close()`.

Comment: @eryksun first one didn't work, second one raises: `PermissionError: [WinError 5]`

Comment: Then you're not elevated as an administrator that has the right to modify the local machine settings. Instead use `winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Comment: @eryksun yep found that in another question and worked, thanks for help